# How to change the value of a variable after some line of code - python

Tags: python, variables

How can I change a variable's value after some line of code has passed ?

for example

```
hungerlevel= "very high"
print (hungerlevel)
for i in range (0,3):
   print ("I ate an apple")
```

and then after this loop make the variable's value change to

```
hungerlevel= "low"
print(hungerlevel)
```

So make the program something like

```
hungerlevel= "very high"
print (hungerlevel)
for i in range (0,3):
   print ("I ate an apple")
hungerlevel= "low"
print(hungerlevel)
```

So that at the end the result showed would be

```
Very high 
I ate an apple
I ate an apple
I ate an apple
low
```

Comment: How can you? You just did!

Comment: What's wrong with what you did? I don't know if their is other way than reinitializing it

Comment: That's exactly what your code does?

Comment: What's wrong with current code? Do you wish to add anything more you've not spoken about?

Comment: Your code does exactly that. Are you trying to do something more?

Comment: Then what is your expected output? Nothing seems to be wrong in your code

Comment: Ok since this is appears to be good, I am a owrking on a program that generates a table with data based on a name i give as input, but incorporating the program with a GUI and infiniteloop() makes so that when I generate the table, and the try to generate the next one, the data from the previous table is also added to the second one generated. How can I make sure that every time I enter a name, no data from previous inputs gets in the way? Sorry for the oversimplified question

Comment: `for i in range(999999)` will still have the same behaviour...

Comment: @EdoardoMaschio, Your comment is entirely different from your question. Could you add it to your question, please?

Comment: Set a dedicated object to pass into the table, and then before you restart the loop wipe the object and start again.

Comment: Is this a homework question?